# Does the Nash embedding theorem extend to pseudo-Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Does the Nash embedding theorem extend to pseudo-Riemannian manifolds?

More precisely, can any ($\mathcal{C}^k$ for some specified $k$) pseudo-Riemannian manifold be isometrically embedded into some [pseudo-Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space)? If so, can the dimension of the pseudo-Euclidean space be bounded by some absolute function of the manifold's dimension? More strongly, can the positive and negative indices in the pseudo-Euclidean space be separately bounded by some absolute function of the pseudo-Riemannian manifold's metric signature?

Comment: looks like there's an analog: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127734/nash-embedding-theorems-for-pseudo-riemannian-manifolds

Comment: At least for the Lorentzian case, you need additional conditions on the manifold for it to be isometrically embeddable in Minkowski space: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4439.pdf

Comment: @AlexD Do you happen to know whether those additional conditions hold in general for the "physically reasonable" spacetimes that are studied in general relativity? (I know that this question may not have an entirely precise answer.)

Comment: Note that the additional conditions burn down to essentially stable causality. Then it depends on what you consider "physically reasonable". People study all kinds of spacetimes also in general relativity that contain closed causal loops like Gödel's spacetime or time machine spacetimes (e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0503077). Both not stably causal, but probably also not "physically reasonable". Other commonly used spacetimes in, e.g., cosmology or black holes (say Schwarzschild or Robertson-Walker) are typically globally hyperbolic. So, no problem there.